# case with params key rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, case

i'm  doing this in my code product controller

```
def index
 if params[:tag]
      #do filter based on tag 
 else
    if params[:category]
      #do filter based on category 
    else
      #default. no filter            
    end
 end
end
```

it work fine. How to achieve the same thing using case? i just can get it to work

```
case <something?>
 when <tag?> 
    #do filter based on tag 
 when <category?>
    #do filter based on category 
 else
    #default      
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do

```
def index
  case
  when params[:tag]
    # Do filter based on tag 
  when params[:category]
    # Do filter based on category 
  else
    # Default. no filter            
  end
end
```

Comment: Yup! works like a charm. didn't know we don't always have to put something after case statement. Thank you Sir :)

Comment: Rubocop (Ruby linter) warns: 
`warning  rubocop:C  [Corrected] Style/EmptyCaseCondition:` Do not use empty `case` condition, instead use an `if` expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts case variable
when 1
  # variable value 1 for tag
  #do filter based on tag 
when 2
  # variable value 2 for category
  #do filter based on category 
else
  #default. no filter
end
```

simple syntax for case statement is

```
case expr0
when expr1, expr2
   stmt1
when expr3, expr4
   stmt2
else
   stmt3
end
```